# Pushing Custom Fields from Opportunity Line items to new Quote Line Items

Tags: visual-workflow, custom-field, opportunity-lineitem, quote, quotelineitem

So - I know there are some answers for this already in the form of a couple of apps available on the AppExchange, plus one from "douglascayers" which seems to do exactly what I'm trying to achieve here. This specific example I can't get to install correctly on Sandbox or Production and despite posting there for some support it's still been over 2 years since any comms were last seen so not hopeful of anything soon. This is similar with many of the other already developed options - Lots from 8 years back which don't look to be maintained anymore.

As you've probably worked out, but I'm looking to get my custom field data from Opportunity Line Items (Products) into the Quote Line items which are generated upon quote creation. This is essential, as I've got to pull through data to allow 'groupings' on the Quote PDF which are populated earlier in my processes.

I've found some apps which also work on the 'Quote Sync' function, but I don't need this. I need 'Opp Line Items -> Quote Line Items' rather than 'Quote Line Items -> Opp Line Items'.

I'm fluent in Flow, but not Apex. I could build a flow to get associated Opportunity Line Items on Quote Creation, then add the extra data from these into the new Quote Line Items, but as far as I know there won't be a reference to identify the exact Opp Line Item the Quote Line Item came from.

So could anyone help here?
I'm getting close to ripping out the standard Salesforce Opportunity Product functionality, build my own and use Flow to populate Quote Line Item data with a lot more flexibility upon Quote creation!

Many thanks in advance.
James

Comment: Flow is your friend if you're going to do this yourself.  Some useful comments on this at https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdjUFUAZ/enable-quotes-to-sync-custom-line-item-fields

Comment: you want to avoid at all costs `ripping out the standard Salesforce Opportunity Product functionality, build my own`

Comment: Thanks @identigral - I've Upvoted. Originally posted in 2010 which is a another concern for me.

Comment: @cropredy, and why is that? I understand it will limit any future developments using this area but with our company structure and processes I don't really see it being used as anything more than something that holds products aligned with the opp. That being said, hindsight is a wonderful thing.

Comment: reasons: benefits from SFDC R&D and ISV R&D diminished with custom solution

Comment: okay, thanks a lot. I think I'm going to have to redsign an area of my system so that rather than populating opp line items (from another object) it populates the quote and line items directly. Flow to save the day.